# Django model inheritance: access to child object from parent queryset

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model

I'm have some models in my django project like these:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Tea(Product):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/tea')

class Coffee(Product):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/coffee')
```

In my ListView I'm have queryset which get me 5 available products:

```py
Product.objects.filter(available=True)[:5]
```

In my template I would like render image from Tea/Coffee, how i can access from Product queryset to Tea/Coffee child object?

```html
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.????.image.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem with [django-model-utils](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils) package.

Update parent model:

```py
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = InheritanceManager()
```

my queryset:

```py
Product.objects.filter(available=True).select_subclasses()[:5]
```

and now i can use in template properties for submodels:

```html
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.image.url }}
{% endfor %}
```